# How to set another color in the below attribute?

Tags: android

I’m trying to set another color in in below mentioned attribute but it showing me error.

```
 <TextView
    android:text="Happy Birthday! ABHISHEK :)"
    android:background="@android:color/blue"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />
```

Comment: How are you trying to set another color?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: 1) which color you are trying to set? 2)  Which error is it showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting blue color which is not available on `@android:color`, you can set color `android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"` or,

On your **colors.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="colorPrimary">#441969</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#361454</color>
    <!--<color name="colorAccent">#361454</color>-->
    <color name="colorAccent">#FFB700</color>

    <color name="colorYellow">#FFB700</color>
    <color name="primaryLight">#7E4995</color>

    <color name="blue">#2ea747</color>
    <color name="black">#000000</color>

</resources>
```

Use Resource color you set your textview background color:

**By xml :**

```
android:background="@color/blue"
```

**By Java Code :**

```
 textView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
```

Reference : https://android--examples.blogspot.in/2015/01/textview-background-color-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

If you Want to apply color from android resource then there are three combination available for you .

> holo_blue_dark  ,     holo_blue_bright ,    holo_blue_light

SO you can use one of this like.

```
<TextView
    android:text="Happy Birthday! ABHISHEK :)"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to implement android default color on a background which is not available that's why to give you an error message you can use below code for apply background color on TextView.

in xml :

```
android:background="@color/blue"
```

values 
  - color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
    <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
</resources>
```

You can define your color code in color.xml